# For each loop in VBA unexpectedly skipping rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have written this code, that is part of a bigger problem. Initially it was supposed to start transfer some data from a worksheet to another.. but it keeps skipping rows, it copies one, skips then copies the other one, skips ,copies,skip... I am using the Select method just to test, instead of copy.

```
Dim sharepointSheet As Worksheet
Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
Dim sharepointTable As Range

'Auxliary variable
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim RowLast As Long



Set sharepointSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sharepoint List")
Set masterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master List")

Set sharepointTable = masterSheet.Range("A2", "F133")


For Each row In sharepointTable.Rows
    row.Cells(row.row, 3).Select

   ' RowLast = masterSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1
   ' masterSheet.Cells(RowLast, "A").PasteSpecial

Next row
```

Comment: something in your loop is also incrementing the row counter. might be row +1

Comment: I though about that, but even when I put the comment mark on front of those lines, as it is in the example, it keeps selecting in the same way

Comment: The only thing I could think of was that the range comes from a formatted table...but it cant be it..I guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are having the problem because you are selecting the row relative to you `row` range rather than the worksheet range.

If you change the select line to the following it will solve your problem:

```
masterSheet.Cells(row.row, 3).Select
```

Also not that it's not a good idea to use variables such as `row` for a range because it can get very confusing!

Comment: It works.. rather strange though, it should make sense in both ways, shouldn't it?

Comment: You can think of the `row` range as a new reference point on the worksheet when you specify `Cells` from it. So when you start at the first `row`, `row.Cells(1,1)` will be the same row, `row.Cells(2,1)` will be the next etc.   By doing `row.Cells(row.row, 1)` for row 2 its, effectively row 3 on the worksheet.  Geez I hope that makes sense, too many rows in there.  If you could accept the answer too, that'd be swell :)